# How to debug web page in "Amazon Kids Browser" - can't use chrome inspect when in Kids Profile

Tags: browser, adb, kindle-fire, usb-debugging

I'm trying to debug an issue with a web application that can be used by children using the Amazon Kindle Fire devices, that use their proprietory "Amazon Kids Browser".  Which has a user agent of :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; KFRAWI Build/RS8321.1920N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 AmazonKidsBrowser/2099110"

where as when it's in the main adult profile on the device the user agent is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; KFRAWI) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/112.7.1 like Chrome/112.0.5615.213 Safari/537.36

I've been able to setup USB debugging for the main adult profile on the device - via enabling USB debugging, and the android adb drivers and can open the url in a browser on the device and successfully connect in chrome using chrome://inspect.

**But** when I open the same web page in the "Web Browser" from a kids profile on the same device, chrome://inspect doesn't show an "inspect" link.

I'm assuming it's do with USB debugging allowed settings for the kids profile, but there is no way I can see of enabling that.

Something is going wrong with the javascript in the Kids Browser that is messing up a text box in an HTML app and I can't figure out what part of the code is doing it, without getting to debug it.

Thanks